# Using R to text mine and extract words

Tags: r, regex, substring, text-mining

I asked a similar questions before but i still need some help/be pointed into the right direction.

I am trying to locate certain words within a column that consists of a SQL statement on all the rows and extract the next word in R studio.

Example: lets call this dataframe "SQL

```
      |    **UserID**    |      **SQL Statement** 

 1   |    N781          |   "SELECT A, B FROM Table.1 p JOIN Table.2 pv ON 
                            p.ProdID.1ProdID.1 JOIN Table.3 v ON pv.BusID.1 = 
                            v.BusID WHERE SubID = 1 ORDER BY v.Name;"

2      |  N283          |   "SELECT D, E FROM Table.11 p JOIN Table.2 pv ON 
                           p.ProdID.1ProdID.1 JOIN Table.3 v ON pv.BusID.1 = 
                           v.BusID WHERE SubID = 1 ORDER BY v.Name;"
```

So I am trying to pull out the table name. So I am trying to find the words "From" and "Join" and pulling the next table names.

I have been using some code with help from earlier:

I make the column "SQL Statement" in a list of 2 name "b"

I use the code:

```
z <- mapply(grepl,"(FROM|JOIN)",b)
```

which gives me a True and fasle for each word in each list.

```
z <- mapply(grep,"(FROM|JOIN)",b)
```

The above is close. It give me a position of every match in each of the lists.

But I am just trying to find the word Join or From and take the text word out. I was trying to get an output something  like

```
      |    **UserID**    |      **SQL Statement**                                | Tables 

 1   |    N781          |   "SELECT A, B FROM Table.1 p JOIN Table.2 pv ON       | Table.1, Table.2          
                            p.ProdID.1ProdID.1 JOIN Table.3 v ON pv.BusID.1 =       
                            v.BusID WHERE SubID = 1 ORDER BY v.Name;"

2      |  N283          |   "SELECT D, E FROM Table.11 p JOIN Table.2 pv ON 
                           p.ProdID.1ProdID.1 JOIN Table.3 v ON pv.BusID.1 =    | Table.11, Table.31 
                           v.BusID WHERE SubID = 1 ORDER BY v.Name;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working script which uses base R options.  The inspiration here is to leverage `strsplit` to split the query string on the keywords `FROM` or `JOIN`.  Then, the first separate word of each resulting term (except for the first term) should be a table name.

```
sql <- "SELECT A, B FROM Table.1 p JOIN Table.2 pv ON 
        p.ProdID.1ProdID.1 JOIN Table.3 v ON pv.BusID.1 = 
        v.BusID WHERE SubID = 1 ORDER BY v.Name;"

terms <- strsplit(sql, "(FROM|JOIN)\\s+")

out <- unlist(lapply(terms, function(x) gsub("^([^[:space:]]+).*", "\\1", x)))

out <- out[2:length(out)]
out

[1] "Table.1" "Table.2" "Table.3"
```

### Demo

To understand better what I did, follow the demo and have a look at the `terms` list which resulted from splitting.

**Edit:**

Here is a link to another demo which shows how you might use the above logic on a vector of query strings, to generate a list of vector of tables, for each query

### Demo

Comment: This seems to get the tables and I tried to use some of this logic to be able to use it on a columns and a list, but it just gives me a long list of  table names even if they are from a different row. Could you give me a pointer on what to use to be able to get the format i mentioned in the questions ?

Comment: @Jim.W Given that I have a bit of logic here, I might just throw everything into a function.  Then, you could `apply` over a vector of query strings, and generate the output you expect.

Comment: @Jim.W I added a second demo link to my answer which shows what you might do to handle a vector of query strings.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am still getting familiar with the functions you have made. Do you have any resources that break it down logically. I have visited many websites but not seems to break it in a nice way? In any case, appreciate the quick answer and demo

Comment: I don't think I can break it down any more than I already have.  Try to go line by line until it makes sense.  Stack Overflow is not really about giving full tutorials.

Comment: I just meant any links that helped you understand making functions and loops